# Image handling in Java

Tags: java, image, png, transparency, gif

I'm thinking about the best way to do two things in Java:

1. merge two images, the background one in .PNG and the other in .GIF or .PNG (has transparency and is to overlap the first one);
2. convert the merged image to .GIF (with transparency).

I don't want to render them, just to handle the images in the java class and write the resultant image to a file.

Can anyone help me? What's the best way to do this?
Thank you!

EDIT:
Thank you all for the suggestions!
This was what I ended up using! Pretty simple!

```
BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
WritableRaster raster = background.getRaster();
BufferedImage layer = ImageIO.read(new File("overlay.png"));
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)background.getGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(layer,72,80,null);
```

About the second problem, I still can't save this with .gif extension with transparency.
This

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"gif",file);
```

creates the .gif image file but it loses the transparency!
Does anyone know how can I do this? JAI also doesn't have the gif encoder.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of your application, but if this is server-based high performance stuff, I've had much better results shelling out to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) than using Java's image libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ben. I appreciate your point of view, not neglecting a heavy server side operation. Yet I would like to see the available options for performing this directly with some java library. Any advice? I edited the question and clarified some details.

Comment: Sorry.. I can't remember specifics in Java. The ImageIO class and java.awt.Image have some useful things to poke at in them. 

By the way, you *do* want to "render" the image. The use of that term in images/graphics refers to any act of creating pixel data, not just displaying on the screen. You'll need to render to some graphics context, and then take the bytes in the context and save them to a file. See Laurent K's link again-- I suspect you might find what you need there.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this link](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=130031) could help ?

It is the same to render an image on a component and to paint an image.

Instead of painting in the paint method, you'll have to create a method createImage(). The sample provided in the link could be adapted like this:
(in java, painting on a component, on an image, on printer output... is everywhere the same. You get a graphics, you paint).

```
public BufferedImage createImage(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage image - new BufferedImage(...);



    Graphics2D g2 = image.getGraphics();

    Point2D center =  new Point2D.Float(image.getHeight( ) / 2, image.getWidth( ) / 2);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(center.getX( ) - (bi2.getWidth( ) / 2), center.getY( ) - (bi2.getHeight( ) / 2));

    g2.transform(at);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.drawImage(bi2, 0, 0, null);

    Composite c = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .35f);
    g2.setComposite(c);

    at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(center.getX( ) - (bi1.getWidth( ) / 2), center.getY( ) - (bi1.getHeight( ) / 2));
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawImage(bi1, 0, 0, null);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Laurent. I don't want to render the image, just write the resultant image to a file!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding an external dependency, you can use the **[JMagick bindings](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html)** to ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

Definintely check out [JAI](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/iio-141084.html) ([api](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/index.html)).

It will allow you to load and store images that were encoded in basically any known format (png and gif included) and allow you to efficiently operate on the images once they've been loaded.

In particular you're probably looking for something like the [CompositeDescriptor](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/CompositeDescriptor1.html).