# How to merge two GIFs in Java?

Tags: java, transparent, gif, animated-gif

I have to GIFs with the same size. One in animated and transparent, the other one is only plaintext. How can I merge both so that the animated one is on top and I can see the text tru the transparent parts and I only have to display one GIF in my app?!

Cheers

Comment: Is this just for a single gif, or multiple? If just for a single, I would think using a image editing program would yield better results as opposed to learning to handle the image in a complex manner using Java. Also for clarity, do you actually want to merge the two images into a single image, or simply display them as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Layers' is what first comes to mind and what seems to be the solution in this related question:

- [Image handling in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2222980/701884)